# Unable to mount Samba share as ReadWrite

Tags: samba

I've installed Samba on machine msc001y. I want to access it's shared folders on msc001.

Both machines have the same users (which are mirrored on Samba)

```
msc (5001), james (5002), rachel (5003).
```

Both machines have the same groups:

```
grp_public (2001), grp_personal (2002)
```

`msc`, `james` and `rachel` all have access to `grp_public`. 
Only `james` and `rachel` have access to `grp_personal`.

I've performed:

```
chgrp -R grp_public /mnt/local/int001/media/public/
chgrp -R grp_personal /mnt/local/int001/media/personal/

chmod 2775 /mnt/local/int001/media/public/
chmod 2770 /mnt/local/int001/media/personal/
```

I've added to smb.conf on msc001y:

Within [global]

```
# Inherit ownership of the parent directory for new files and directories
inherit owner = unix only
# Inherit permissions of the parent directory for new files and directories
inherit permissions = yes

create mask = 0775
directory mask = 2775
force create mode = 0775
force directory mode = 2775
```

then within...

```
[public]

comment = Public Stuff
path = /mnt/local/int001/media/public
public = yes
writable = no
printable = no
write list = @grp_public, msc, james, rachel
inherit acls = yes
```

Before I mount [public], the mount point lists as (ie: RWX for Owner and Group):

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 msc grp_public    0 Jul 25 23:07 public
```

Once I've mounted it, it becomes (ie: RWX for Owner, RX no W for Group):

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 msc grp_public    0 Jul 25 23:07 public
```

It is mounted with:

```
//msc001y/public /mnt/remote/msc001y/public cifs user,nofail,_netdev,vers=3.1.1,uid=msc,gid=grp_public,credentials=/mnt/local/data/.Credentials/james.cred 0 0
```

If I'm loggged in as `msc` I get read-write as it's the owner, but if I'm james or rachel, I'm stuck with ReadOnly.

Why does the folder default to RX when I mount to it when it is RWX before?

Note: All files within the shared folder are RWX|RWX|R_X

Answer (score 2):

You specified `@grp_public, @msc, @james, @rachel` in the `write list`.
But only `grp_public` is a group; `msc`, `james` and `rachel` are users.

The correct write list should be:

`write list = msc, james, rachel, @grp_public`

Also see `man 5 smb.conf`:

> `write list (S)`
>   This is a list of users that are given read-write access to a service. If the connecting user is in this list then they will be given write access, no matter what the read only option is set to. The list can include group names using the @group syntax.
>   Note that if a user is in both the read list and the write list then they will be given write access.
>
> `Default: write list =`
>
> `Example: write list = admin, root, @staff`

Comment: I've corrected this, but nothing changes.  The big question is why do the permissions for GROUP change from RWX to RX when the remote folder is mounted?

Comment: You have all kinds of funky `mount.cifs` parameters, such as `user`, `uid`, and `gid`. Please remove them and retry. Furthermore, I presume the credentials file contains only two or maybe three lines (`username`, `password` and maybe `domain`)?

Comment: Funky options removed and yes credentials files has username=REDACTED and password=REDACTED... No change.

Comment: Any other suggestions @Edward

Comment: I've gone over it one more time, and the only discrepancy that still shows is the use of `grp_media_public` and `grp_media_personal` in the `chgrp` commands. Shouldn't those be `grp_public` and `grp_personal`?

Comment: That's a typo, I've corrected. I'm trying out SSHFS as an alternative as I've always had Samba issues without applying 777 which I don't want to do. Thanks for your input.